# Pension reforms. Why is the debate constrained to raising the retirement age or not, with no intermediate solutions?

Tags: europe, france, retirement

This question was inspired by the [French pension reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_French_pension_reform_bill), but also in other European countries the situation is not different. The debate seems framed between the two extremes. Increase or not the retirement age. I never heard about proposals or studies whether intermediate solutions could help. There could be for example part time work after a certain number of years of contribution. Or it could be reduced contribution after a threshold to make older workers more employable. It could also be mandatory transfer to less demanding roles for demanding jobs for which there is a lower retirement age.

Anyway what I cited above are just examples. My question here is why the arguments are: raise the retirement age or not, nothing else.

Note. While the media draw a lot of attention on workers that for one reason or the other work for the government and their jobs are safe a big part of the problem and the [protests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_French_pension_reform_strikes) are old workers in the private sector who remain unemployed in their late fifties and will not have a stable income until the retirement age.

Comment: Related question: [Why is there an official retirement age?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77768/why-is-there-an-official-retirement-age/77777#77777)

Comment: Is that as much - or more - about economics than politics?

Answer (score 4):

To quote some World Bank [slides](https://pubdocs.worldbank.org/en/931351574287665237/SPJCC19-PCC-D4S3-Weaver-The-Political-Economy-of-Pension-Reform-final.pdf):

> Pension Reform Policy Options:
>
> 1. Refinancing:
>
>    - Increase payroll tax base or rate
>    - Add additional earmarked revenues or general taxes
> 2. Retrenchment:
>
>    - Reduce benefits (e.g., change indexation)
>    - Reduce eligibility (e.g., raise standard retirement age)
> 3. Restructuring, e.g.:
>
>    - Add (or substitute) defined contribution tiers
>    - Add automatic balancing mechanisms ([NDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notional_Defined_Contributions))
>    - Add “boundary straddling” automatic stabilizing mechanisms
>
> ...usually tried in roughly that order

Generally speaking people on the center-right don't like to pile up more/higher taxes/contributions. And also generally speaking, people don't like their benefits cut, but that did happen e.g. in Greece, simply because cutting pensions in half has no real substitute in terms of raising the retirement age.

As for the last part (3), it's complicated to add multiple layers of contributions etc. Generally speaking [it's](https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/sites/a21ebf8f-en/index.html?itemId=/content/component/a21ebf8f-en) the poor[er] who pay more of their income towards pensions anyways. And in NDC [Wikipedia]

> Unlike in PAYG pension system, there is no guarantee that the worker can expect decent pension in his retirement, since it is based solely on his contributions and the notional rate of return.

Anyway, going back to the World Bank slides, there's this arguing against the more complicated schemes:

> Stealth mechanisms for loss imposing pension reforms [suffer from lack of]
> Clarity--if workers are to adapt successfully to new
> pension policies, they must be given clear signals early
> about changing their savings and retirement behavior.

While France is largely a PAYG country, its [system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensions_in_France#Mandatory_state_pension_provision) is already using various tiers etc. Yeah, they could tweak those and make just *some* people worse off. But what happened when some people in France thought they were unfairly targeted by diesel fuel taxes? [A: Years of protests.]

---

> My question here is why the arguments are: raise the retirement age or not, nothing else.

That seems to be the most contentious issue, and traditionally [has been so](https://ec.europa.eu/social/BlobServlet?docId=17316&langId=en), see e.g. [2010 protests](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2023/01/31/why-is-the-french-pension-age-so-low), but it's hardly the only measure that was considered/included, although I only found [this](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/politics/article/2023/01/10/pension-reform-france-to-raise-minimum-retirement-age-to-64-by-2030_6011092_5.html) bit in English from January, so I don't know how much of it made it to the final law:

> "Another key measure that the government is counting on to get the reform accepted is the increase of the minimum pension for low-income workers who have a full career to 85% of the net minimum wage, i.e. nearly €1,200 at present. A measure extended to current pensioners. "Nearly two million small pensions will be increased," said Elisabeth Borne." [...]
>
> "More than ten years after the abolition of the gradual cessation of activity, the government announced the return of a system of gradual retirement in the civil service, "on the same principles as the existing system for employees and the self-employed," according to a government press kit. We will allow civil servants "to go part-time two years before the retirement age", i.e. from the age of 62, said Ms. Borne."

Comment: The problem with France rather then the different tiers is the fact that for different workers there are different rules depending on the job category or private/government sector jobs.

Comment: @FluidCode: they are broad classes. So either they target the agri workers or the state employees, etc. Maybe targeting just one group would be fair, IDK, but more likely to guarantee that group would vote against LREM/RE at the next elections. There is some risk to "make everyone unhappy" too as in 2010 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_French_pension_reform_strikes

Comment: The problem is that many tiers often are complicated because there are different rules for different workers. Not because there are different options that apply to all the workers.

Comment: @FluidCode: true, but everyone takes the status quo as an entitlement. It's even   a point in those World Bank slides; I thought it too obvious to add to my answer.

Comment: @FluidCode: The EC would agree with you that "In the French pension system, the legislator can use four types of measure to implement reforms: change the rate of contributions; vary the level of pensions; modify the duration of work required to claim a full pension; and change the SPA [statutory pensionable age]. The latter, which is simple and immediately visible, is the most frequently used measure and is subject to the most political debate. It appears to be the measure that maintains, or even accentuates, inequalities the most." https://ec.europa.eu/social/BlobServlet?docId=17316&langId=en

Comment: OTOH that's not quite the EC saying it but the European Social Policy Network (ESPN).

Comment: BTW, the actual Borne reform not without some social dressing: "Another key measure that the government is counting on to get the reform accepted is the increase of the minimum pension for low-income workers who have a full career to 85% of the net minimum wage, i.e. nearly €1,200 at present. A measure extended to current pensioners. "Nearly two million small pensions will be increased," said Elisabeth Borne." https://www.lemonde.fr/en/politics/article/2023/01/10/pension-reform-france-to-raise-minimum-retirement-age-to-64-by-2030_6011092_5.html

Comment: @FluidCode: and something that you did ask about "More than ten years after the abolition of the gradual cessation of activity, the government announced the return of a system of gradual retirement in the civil service, "on the same principles as the existing system for employees and the self-employed," according to a government press kit. We will allow civil servants "to go part-time two years before the retirement age", i.e. from the age of 62, said Ms. Borne." That was in January, I'm not 100% what went into the law.

Answer (score -4):

> There could be for example part time **work** after a certain number of years of contribution. Or it could be **reduced contribution** after a threshold to make older workers more employable.

Your proposed solution is to increase the retirement age, with extra steps, but worse. Not pension (no free time), and also not money. Not only that your proposal is bad, but it is additionally offensive - and that is why nobody has the guts to propose it.

---

Additionally

Besides government employees and people "unemployed in their late fifties", there are other people affected, in several ways. The main issue is that the retirement age is already frighteningly close to the life expectancy. Pushing the retirement age even further practically cancels retirement. And this is true even before we consider health issues and other details.

Comment: Please avoid straw man arguments. My question is not whether the examples I made would work or not. My question is about the constrained debate and the absence of any alternative proposal.

Comment: Then please give an example which would make sense. And I did not use any "straw man". I just answered your question. If your examples are not relevant, please edit the question and remove them. As a result, I *might* remove my answer.

Comment: "please give an example which would make sense" Are you still trying  to derail the question off topic?

Comment: :O derail? It is your own question, it is YOUR job to make it clear.

Comment: "The main issue is that the retirement age is already frighteningly close to the life expectancy." That's just incorrect.

Comment: @Roland: for some demographic, you might be right. But overall, especially if we take into account factors like health, retirement already comes too late (if at all). Unfortunately, the retirement age is decided strictly on economic reasons as of late, with disregard for the human being. That is why there is so much unrest in so many places (maybe not all at the same time).

Comment: @virolino You mean economic decisions such as being able to pay the pensions based on the current working force?

Comment: @virolino The retirement age in Germany is 67 years. Mean life expectancy of men (at birth in recent years) is 78.5 years. Women live even longer.

Comment: @JoeW: that is what I had in mind as an immediate example, there might be others too.

Comment: @Roland: According to this page (https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/products-eurostat-news/-/edn-20191118-1), 78.9 in Germany is an expectation for the people in "lucky" areas. The unlucky areas have a life expectancy more similar with the Eastern Europe.

Comment: @virolino One of the main reasons why retirement funding is such a big issue today is precisely that people on average live a lot more years after retirement that they did 20, 50  or 100 years ago. Rich people tend to live longer than poor people and that is also an issue for fair retirement benefits. But even poor people today life more years in retirement than people of any wealth did 50 years. Retirement age is nowhere close to average life expectany for any group today. It used to be for male workers in the first half of the 20th century.

Comment: Not that it is necessarily the solution for France, but The Economist frequently talks up part time work as a way to avoid stressing pension and retirement systems.  -1 for being so confrontational and not even articulating clearly what the actual economic objections are.  *The main issue is that the retirement age is already frighteningly close to the life expectancy.*  In what country?  France with 83 years?

Comment: @Roland is that before or after worldwide life expectency dropped by about 3 years in the last 3 years due to our failure to stop COVID spread?

Comment: @user253751 That's [life expectancy at birth as the average of 2019-2021](https://www-genesis.destatis.de/genesis/online?sequenz=tabelleErgebnis&selectionname=12621-0002&zeitscheiben=16&sachmerkmal=ALT577&sachschluessel=ALTVOLL000,ALTVOLL020,ALTVOLL040,ALTVOLL060,ALTVOLL065,ALTVOLL080#abreadcrumb). There is no impact of COVID on this value. Even life expectancy of 80 year olds doesn't appear to have gone down. It only increased less than in previous years.