Why is "no representation without taxation" not considered a valid democratic principle?
No taxation without representation has had a long history and was (one of) the triggers for the American revolution against the British Empire. But why doesn't the principle work the other way around? For example the receipt of pensions or welfare could be conditioned on giving up the right to vote.
I'm of course aware of the fallacy of the converse but I'm curious as to why democracies seems to have rejected this idea.

Do you intend this to be a principle on the level of regions like its converse or on the level of individuals?

@quarague individual, based off whether you're a net tax payer or receiver. But I guess could be regional?

Maybe the question could add a bit more details how that would supposed to work, like how it could still be a democracy then. Currently I have problems imagining how that could work. Can the question be made clearer?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution done

But how could giving up the right to vote for welfare be a democratic principle? You mean people sell their votes more or less?

There were versions of this in England: before 1918, poor men who moved into municipal workhouses usually lost the right to vote in all elections, while female heads of households or businesses who paid local property taxes could usually  vote in municipal elections.

I’m voting to close this question because "critique of my political system" is a "request for discussion" rather than a genuine question.  In this particular case it's pretty obvious that a system in which substantial numbers of (mostly poorer) people are unrepresented  isn't democracy

The reverse would presumably be "If you don't pay taxes, you don't get to vote". Is that what you're asking about?

"For example the receipt of pensions or welfare could be conditioned on giving up the right to vote." What does this have to do with taxes?

The real reverse is no representation at all (collectively), in a society without any taxation. This is how essentially all of the remaining non-symbolic monarchies work. In Saudi Arabia, the people have no say in national government, and pay no taxes. Elected representatives were the price paid historically by absolute monarchs who needed to raise funds from a merchant class through taxes because rents from royal lands in an agrarian economy were no longer sufficient to fund a modern state.

@ohwilleke: they pay VAT in SA these days. https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/saudi-arabia/corporate/other-taxes Presumably you're going to say that kings always taxed commerce somehow and that that's not a 'tax' for the purpose of this discussion.

@ohwilleke: even the Sumerian kings taxed commercial transactions https://taxtech.digital/2023/07/26/taxes-ancient-sumer-assyria-babylonia/ In fact, those seem to be the first taxes on record.

The situation where the king had so many assets they could easily sell--like oil-- without literally diminishing their kingdom territory-wise is rather the exception than the rule, I think.

Probably the only somewhat comparable situation was an 'ever'-expanding kingdom like the Mongols had for a while, the 'job' of the king was to redistribute that income gained from looting/conquering https://blogs.icrc.org/religion-humanitarianprinciples/mongol-laws-of-war/

And when the Mongols codified their practices, "Rule 8" assured that the king/han/emperor received a cut from all the loot.


individual, based off whether you're a net tax payer or receiver.

united-states
I'm not sure about other countries, but in the US a voting poll tax, i.e. that had to be paid per-capita in order to vote was strongly associated with Jim Crow laws, i.e. racism. These were introduced between 1875 and 1910 mostly in Southern states, as a blowback against [or attempt to circumvent] the liberalization that had occurred as a result of the 15th Amendment.
There were attempts to repeal such laws during the New Deal era, but these were only successful in a couple of states. A federal-level repeal came in the form of the 24th amendment, in the 1960s, in the context of the broader desegregation measures.  (SCOTUS had held voting poll taxes as constitutional in 1937.) Unsurprisingly, the 24th Amendment was mostly ratified by the other US states.
Assessing whether "you're a net tax payer or receiver" can also turn rather complex, depending on the time frame. E.g. when a businessman declares a loss for one year and pays nothing then, should they still get to vote? FWTW, Georgia had some kind of cumulative poll tax, as Wikipedia recounts:

Georgia created a cumulative poll tax requirement in 1877: men of any race 21 to 60 years of age had to pay a sum of money for every year from the time they had turned 21, or from the time that the law took effect.

Anyhow, if we take a cumulative approach, clearly mostly older people [who made it rich] would be the ones able to vote. One might argue that student debt is punishing enough as it is, etc.


But I guess could be regional?

Assuming the proposal here is that a "net tax receiver" region doesn't get to vote, I can see the [counter-]argument that in many/most countries there will be effective net transfers from the richer to the poorer regions in many setups, and that that is actually desirable to counteract the centrifugal tendencies that might appear otherwise. Leaving sizeable regions without a vote (as a result of this proposal) might entice them to secede, even if they end up poorer, in the short term. (Perhaps Bangladesh is such an example. They were reportedly poorer per capita than West Pakistan when they seceded, but they did it nonetheless.)
OTOH the converse/pro argument surely exists [and perhaps has more traction than voting poll taxes these days], e.g. as expressed by Lega Nord in Italy [or at least the cartoonish/simplified version that I recall from the 1990s] that the South is part of the country not only for free but making a profit [at the expense of the North].  (N.B. a few more minutes on Google finds that the LN of today apparently isn't the same as under Bossi, even in that 'Padania' respect.)
Of course, the latter argument only works until there's a war or something where you need the warm bodies from the poorer regions (see Russia today). Foreign mercenaries being ultimately more expensive and less reliable, even in the words of one Italian. (And if someone objects that Russia is irrelevant as not democratic enough, that kind of dynamic isn't so dependent on democracy--see The Casualty Gap that reportedly exist in all post-WW2 armed conflicts involving the US.)
Speaking of wars, the aftermath of WWI saw the greatest franchise expansion in most European countries. Not unsurprisingly after it required masses or armies on a scale not seen before. At least one paper proposes that that was "a rational way for
incumbent elites to wage war effectively on other nations" from then on, although alternative theories such as [preempting] threats of insurrection by (the returning) soldiers also have traction.

Democracies have not embraced this principle because it is blatantly anti-democratic. The political prerogative to raise taxes long predates democracy. Political representation was fought for and slowly expanded over time. There is no popular interest in limiting representation.
Traditionally, well into the nineteenth century, both political representation and taxation (including suffrage in most countries that had it) were traditionally tied to property. When the American Revolution produced the slogan of "no taxation without representation" it effectively went without saying a) that political representation only applies to property holders and b) that such property would be subject to legitimate taxation, given representation.
As the economic structure of societies changed so that more and more people earn their living from wages rather then from the land, limiting representation to property owners became untenable. It was only in the middle of the nineteenth century that the concept of universal manhood suffrage started to be put into practice in most industrializing societies. This did not mean that the prevailing implicit "no representation without taxation" principle suddenly disappeared. Rather the practice of income-based taxation followed roughly in tandem with the wider extension of political representation to the working class.
Today, both representation and taxation are widely spread in democratic societies. Sales tax and/or value added taxes ensure that literally everyone pays taxes now, even if their net tax burden isn't positive. The question equates "receipt of pensions or welfare" with non-taxation, but this assumption is baseless.
Anti-democratic ideologies try to divide people into "makers and takers", claiming that certain people are productive tax-paying citizens while others are parasites unworthy of representation. Those "others" are almost always racialized, if implicitly: illegal immigrants, welfare queens, Jewish bankers. Anti-democratic ideologies don't explicitly use the slogan "no representation without taxation" because it is so easy to counter. It is impossible to exist in modern society without participating in the economy, and therefor taxation, in some non-trivial way. Migrants in particular  have a large positive fiscal impact in the United States, but don't automatically get a path to citizenship.

Good last point about this being an easy fail as a slogan.  "no representation without net taxation" is what the OP and the more 'targeted' slogans generally envisaged. OTOH immigrants can't usually vote right away anyway, and in some countries an immigrant getting citizenship is sometimes tied to being 'economically productive', i.e. not likely to be asking for 'benefits' right away.

In democratic societies, the right to vote is considered a universal right. It should only be taken away in extreme circumstances. For instance, some US states deny the right to vote from convicted felons (and suffrage is usually restored once they have completed their sentence); this is considered part of the punishment (prisoners lose a number of basic rights that other citizens enjoy, such as privacy and autonomy).
If we removed the right to vote from people who receive welfare, we'd essentially be punishing people for being poor. If society really considered being poor something bad that should be punished, why would we give them welfare in the first place? Being poor is already an unfortunate situation by itself, and welfare only mitigates it a little bit. Why would we add to this burden by taking away their right to vote? Poor people are part of society, there's no reason why they should not be able to participate in the democratic process.
Removing suffrage from people receiving a pension makes even less sense. These people have done nothing wrong, they merely lived long enough to retire. And I'm not sure what it has to do with your "no representation without taxation" premise, because pensions may be taxed.
If your basic idea is that if you don't make enough money to pay income tax, you shouldn't get to vote, that seems like flawed public policy. If you feel that would be fair, then it would also be fair for the number of votes to be proportional to the amount of taxes you pay. But that principle would lead to an oligarchy where the top 1% of earners would effectively run the country. We're dangerously close to that already, due to the way they can contribute to campaigns and pay for lobbyists, but at least we don't enshrine it into the voting laws. On the other hand, it could have a benefit that these ultra-rich people might not take advantage of all the loopholes to reduce their taxes (but extra votes might not be worth much to them if they can influence elections other ways).

In re 2nd para: there's actually a fair bit of right-wing theory that being poor is mostly one's choice. And even if it's not choice, some would go further on the social Darwinism angle and say that those who are poor are inferior in some manner, be it genetic etc., so unworthy in some (broader) sense. Just see the 'lite' version of that wrt not giving [as much] right to vote to those w/o children, or giving extra votes to those with children etc.

I find that theory so reprehensible that I barely consider it worth acknowledging.

You cannot ignore the role of the government in managing the economy.
And if the (mis)management of the economy creates an environment where jobs are scarce, or an existing job is erased, and a citizen is forced to go on welfare how is it fair to then demand that these very person affected by the incompetence of the government be denied the right (by "voluntary" disenfranchisement) to question the government?
Denying the poor a voice in governance is an anti-democratic idea that was actually practiced at the height of imperialism and capitalism. Today, it is recognized as anti-democratic as allowing the privileged few to dictate power creates a political condition where it is in the obvious best interest of the privileged to maintain the status quo.

I'll hazard the following opinion:

Indeed it has been said that democracy is the worst form of Government except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time.…’


Winston S Churchill, 11 November 1947

Yes, democracy gets many critics, but one of its main attractions is the notion that everyone gets a say.
This runs straight against the type of notion in this question and consequently a not inconsiderable amount of people think this is a horrible idea.
The US did start out with such barriers, initially, but that's most certainly not what has since captured the imaginations of people aiming for democracy.  Neither does the US much promote its pre-1828 arrangements, so presumably it isn't held in high esteem there either.
Vary the subject - upper age limits, IQ tests, etc... and the general feeling still seems to be a hefty dose of revulsion, combined with suspicion at the capacity of some to game such a system.

Slighly ironic to quote Churchill on this as he had his doubts about extending the franchise, at least pre-WW1 and to soldiers, e.g. he warned in a 1913 speech that that would create a "tremendous trade union" that would "able to force their will on any point they care about sufficiently by the use of lethal weapons".
https://library.fes.de/libalt/journals/swetsfulltext/6260944.pdf

In the same speech he had a more plausible point that in some constituencies, particularly in Ireland, the military vote would have dominated, since few other had the franchise then over there. So, he was also concerned with some kind of fairness. In 1935 he even proposed that voting should be made mandatory, as he was [by then] concerned with declining participation, after the franchise had expanded to all adults in '28.

The entire idea is flawed under the false impression that someone who is getting a pension or welfare isn't paying taxes. You are correct that taxes are one of the reasons for the American revolution but it should be remembered that it was that tax of goods that caused the issue.
Some of the places that people receiving a pension or welfare still pay taxes

Income

Taxes on various retirement income
Taxes on normal income that isn't enough and still leaves the qualified for benefits


Housing

Taxes on home ownership, while there are some areas that have some exemptions based on age those tend to be exceptions rather then the rule
Taxes paid by apartment owners to the tenants living in them


Vehicle

Taxes paid for owning a vehicle and having the right to drive it on the roads


Sales Tax

Regardless of what else they do people pay taxes on almost everything they buy
This type of tax is listed as one of the reasons for the American revolution


Already paid in

Just because someone is receiving some sort of benefit from the government doesn't mean they didn't already pay into the system for that right earlier.



Just because someone is getting benefits from the government doesn't mean that they are not still paying taxes and that they didn't pay for the right to those payments in the past.

The last bullet point is the most relevant one, given the OP's framing. OTOH that still leaves people who'd be [clearly] net recipients even by that kind of calculation: those who are disabled from birth and can't work at all, etc. A more cogent rebuttal on similar but broader grounds is that it negates the idea of insurance (which SocSec is in a way) in which risks are pooled across individuals and the [simply] unlucky ones aren't hit with some arbitrary/unrelated penalty.

@timetakesitstoll not sure I agree with that as the other bullet points show that there is still taxation happening even if someone is getting benefits from the government. It also shows that the taxation is similar in type to what was at issue before the American revolution.

@timetakesitstoll Social Security is not a form of insurance, it’s a transfer from current taxpayers to past taxpayers. Only two countries in the world implement it as a true insurance system: Malaysia and Singapore. See https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48508/do-any-countries-have-a-pensions-system-funded-entirely-by-past-contributions-r

@JonathanReez: I know it's not true insurance since someone born with a crippling disability doesn't pay at all into the scheme... before being born. Normal insurance schemes just reject people who'd be entitled to cash in their policy on day one. It's also why SocSec etc. are referred to by slightly different words like 'social safety net' etc.

@JonathanReez What do you suppose an insurance is? An insurance is pooling money and giving it to those who need it (either as money or as service), promising that if you'd need it you'd also get it. So you take the edge of a crushing risk by paying for it in smaller manageable portions. Whether that is a net negative or positive is a matter of hindsight, that you don't have.

@haxor789 In that case would you call various retirement funds that pool peoples money to be insurance?

@JoeW Difficult. I mean there are pensions that cover unforeseeable risks, like injuries and disabilities or some might cover the breadwinner of a family dying or stuff like that. There it's covering for the odds of something unlikely happening. In case of old age that also used to be the case as retirement age was largely unreachable. But if it's the norm that old people can or even have to collect retirement for a long time, it's difficult. So you either need to pay more, take it later, supplement it or make it a redistribution through taxes, otherwise it's more of a insufficient piggy bank.

Because it's completely anti-democratic? Like seriously do you have any idea what democracy even means? Do you even know what politics means?
Like these words are Greek where polis refers to the city, demos to the people and -archy and -cracy mean "rule or government". So politics was that what concerns the city or more broadly matters of it's inhabitants while the various systems of -archies and -cracies tell you who is in charge of making decisions for the future of the city and it's inhabitants.
So essentially people within the confines of a territory organize themselves as a political group (somewhat like a city). Now that group usually governs itself by rules and regulations and works closer or more loosely together and how that is organized, what the rules are, who makes the rules, to whom do they apply, what goals are followed and what are avoided and so one, all that is what is the subject of "politics".
Now apparently Aristotle distinguished between one ruler,(small) group rulership and majority rulership and between abuse of power for oneself and legitimate rule. Where monarchy (mono-archos = one ruler), aristocracy (rule of the best) and politie are the legit, while tyranny, oligarchy and democracy are the ones abusing power. So what we nowadays call democracy is rather politie (if you got confused about the -archy part), while "monarchy" and "aristocracy" have been tyranny and oligarchy too often to be associated with anything positive.
So modern democracies usually identify their polis (or respectively their country) as being owned collectively by the people: republic (res publica = matter of the people) and see the collective of the people as a the sovereign of said country. Now ideally that would be a direct democratic process where the people would discuss issues directly and come to consensus about how one should move forward. Or more commonly they see themselves as owners and need to affirm any important decisions, but leave the everyday business to a CEO and a board of managers, that they put in place, that are accountable to the people and who regularly need to achieve affirmation by the people or are replaced by them.
Now a crucial problem with political power (so the ability to make decisions for the whole) is that it is a zero sum game, meaning the power of the ruler stems from the powerlessness of the ruled. So whenever you have a concentration of power in the hands of the few, that means a majority is without the ability to decide for themselves.
Which is precisely what would happen in your proposal, where you either remove people from political power, making them subject to the tyranny of tax payers or if you further layer political influence by the amount of taxes paid you'd go full throttle towards plutocracy (rule of the wealthy).
The thing is "political power", is very easy to convert back to monetary gains. If you have the power to make the rules for a country you can easily take advantage of that to fill your pockets. Idk raise the tax level to contribute so that fewer and fewer people do have power. Buy the rest or illegalize them. That is make rules that everyone violates and put them away or collect fines (serves the same purpose as taxes but doesn't count as voting rights...). Redistribute that money to yourself, either directly or as income for holding office or through subsidies for your "businesses". Or just plain old corruption, take money for favors and preferential treatment. It's not hard to run a profit from holding office and being in or being close to power.
So it probably won't take long before that deteriorates into capitalism, by which I don't mean "free markets" or whatnot, but simply "rule by capital". Meaning those who are rich claim power and holding power makes them more rich and powerful.
Like the idea of "no taxation without representation" is that if a government presents itself to you as tyrannical (serves mostly it's own purposes and you've no way of influencing it or participating in it) then you have no moral obligation to support a system that oppresses you.
While no "representation without taxation" is the attempt of a government to shield itself from external influence and participation and to uphold such a tyranny and as said it's quite easy to extend this systems and to exclude ever more people. If it's layered you can even keep the middle class in a state of dread where they constantly hate, fear and are in opposition to the lower classes because they know that could be them if they make the wrong move, they know that they (the middle class) would be the first that the lower class encounters if they revolt and they know they have all right and moral reason to and that they are both exploited and exploiters, which semi-stabilizes this tyranny into some sort of fascism which often enough racializes the lower classes as inherently lazy or undeserving and to further drive them and the middle classes apart from each other to avoid a critical mass that could topple the system.
